# How to apply next/previous classes to LIs for pagination links?

Tags: plugins, css, pagination

I am using the WP-Paginate plug-in and need to apply a class to the containing LIs for the next/previous links. Can someone tell me how to do this? If there's a better/easier way to do this other than using WP-Paginate, then I'm open to suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Happy to say that it's not hard at all to achieve what you are looking for.

As I understand it, [you have to add a call to `wp_paginate()` in *(one of)* your theme*(s)* template file*(s)*](http://svn.wp-plugins.org/wp-paginate/tags/1.2.2/readme.txt) when using this plugin, and that call looks something like this:

```
<?php if(function_exists('wp_paginate')) {
  wp_paginate();
} ?>
```

To do what you need just create your own function, let's call it `mysite_paginate()` and call it instead of the code above.

Within your function `mysite_paginate()` call `ob_start()` to start output buffering, then call `wp_paginate()`, and then call `ob_get_clean()` to capture the output created by `wp_paginate()`.  The final step is to then use a regular expression search and replace with `preg_replace()` to add the classes you want and then echo the results to the browser.

The code you need is below. You can add it to your theme's `functions.php` file or in a `.php` file of a plugin you may be writing:

```
function mysite_paginate() {
  if(function_exists('wp_paginate')) {
    ob_start();
    wp_paginate();
    $html = ob_get_clean();
    $html = preg_replace('#<li>(<a href="[^"]+" class="next">)#Us',
              '<li class="next">$1',$html);
    $html = preg_replace('#<li>(<a href="[^"]+" class="prev">)#Us',
              '<li class="prev">$1',$html);
    echo $html;
  }
}
```

And if all goes as planned, this is what you should expect to see when using an [**element inspector**](http://webkit.org/blog/197/web-inspector-redesign/) with your browser:

[image: Screenshot showing classes added to the HTML output of WordPress]

Comment: Nice post, Mike. I was trying to avoid suggesting anything too "advanced", not knowing the OP's comfort level with WP, but this certainly would do the trick ;)

Comment: @Eric Martin - Thanks. The site is as much about creating a persistent resource that can be found by Google for people with the same question in the future as it is about meeting that persons needs so I try to be thorough. Also, check this out: http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/266/ Maybe you could encourage questions about your plugins here?

Comment: I will definitely be adding this site as a place to get help for my plugins. I've done the same for my jQuery plugin & stackoverflow! They are a great resource.

Comment: @Eric Martin - Just to make sure it was clear, I was suggesting you encourage people to ask questions about *your* plugins here; it will give your plugins more exposure than having the questions be on your site or even on WordPress.org. I'm unclear if I got that across. BTW, I had not heard of your WP-Paginate plugin before but after looking at it I really, really like it. I wrote something similar custom for a client 2 years ago, but wish yours had been available at the time.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel - yup, sorry if my response wasn't clear. I'll be adding this site as a place to get help for my plugins ;)

Comment: @Eric Martin - Cool!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to change:

`<li><a href="http://www.ericmmartin.com/blog/page/2/" class="next">»</a></li>`

To:

`<li class="next"><a href="http://www.ericmmartin.com/blog/page/2/" class="next">»</a></li>`

Besides modifying the source, you could do it with a little jQuery magic:

`$('ol.wp-paginate .next').parent().addClass('next');`

And:

`$('ol.wp-paginate .prev').parent().addClass('prev');`

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not using jQuery. :( Also, using JavaScript to do this could cause the elements to shift once the JavaScript loads.

Comment: I guess the only other reasonable option would be to modify the WP-Paginate code.

Comment: Great to have you here at WordPress Answers. Hope we'll see you around some more.